# Input user defined variables in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to store user defined variables in sql select statement and use that variable in sub query like the following:

```
select user_id, @user_gender:=user_gender 
where user_id in (select user_id from post where post_gender=@user_gender);
```

So what I want to do here is I want to store the user_gender value into a variable and use it in a subquery. I know what I am tryinig to do here can be achieved by joins, but what I am posting this example, because I want to know how to actually store value from a row into a user defined variable.

Also, I am having hard time finding good resources that explains how to use user defined variables. Any recommendations?

Comment: Mysql's online documentation does describe how to use variables in sql statements. You should be a lot more specific as to what you are after. Btw, asking for non-SO resource is off-topic here.

Comment: Too broad unclear off topic resource request. Google has some good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following query :

SELECT user_id FROM post , ( SELECT @user_gender:='MALE' ) AS var WHERE post_gender=@user_gender;

check [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) for reference